# What has .Render() on SSRS2000 WebService been replaced with on SSRS2008?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

We've recently upgraded one of our SSRS2005 servers to SSRS2008 and have found that all of our applications that utilized the reporting services web service for producing reports no longer works.

The first issue is that the web service itself was no longer available at ReportService.asmx, and had been replaced by: ReportService2005.asmx.

We changed our web reference to the new location and we are now getting the message that the .Render() method is not a part of ReportService2005.asmx.  What has the following code implementation been replaced with in SSRS2008?

```
report = rpt.Render(ReportPath + ReportName, this.Format.ToString(), null, devInfo.ToString(), parameters, null, null, out encoding, out mimetype, out parametersUsed, out warnings, out streamids);
```

**EDIT**
After doing some more research, it turns out that the ReportService.asmx was part of SQL 2000 Reporting Services which has now been deprecated out of SQL 2008 Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ReportService.asmx was removed, as you note, you should use ReportExecution2005.asmx and then change the report parameters as required in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of articles on migrating from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008

- [Upgrading Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674.aspx)
- [Reporting Services Backward Compatibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143251.aspx)
- [Report Server Web Service Endpoints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`ReportService.asmx` is deprecated. It has been replaced with:

- `ReportService2005.asmx` - *the management endpoint*
- `ReportExecution2005.asmx` - *the execution endpoint*

There is also a SharePoint proxy endpoint. Here's an article enumerating the 
[Report Server Web Service Endpoints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx) for 2008.